# Displaying array content in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I am getting the error,

**Message: Array to string conversion**

var_dump() shows,

```
  array (size=2)
0 => 
  array (size=2)
    'id' => string '1' (length=1)
    'name' => string 'English' (length=7)
1 => 
  array (size=2)
    'id' => string '2' (length=1)
    'name' => string 'Kannada' (length=7)
```

I have the below code,

```
//model
    public function get_all() {
    $data = array();
    $q = $this->db->get('languages');
    if($q->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach($q->result_array() as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;     
        }
    } 
    $q->free_result();
    return $data;   
}

//controller

   public function list_all(){
    $data['content'] = $this->m_languages->get_all();
    $data['title'] = 'Language';

    $data['main'] = 'language_list';
    $this->load->view('admin_template', $data);
}


//view

   <table>
    <?php

        var_dump($content);

        foreach($content as $id => $name) {
            echo "<tr>
                    <td>
                        $name
                    </td>
                  </tr>";
        }       
    ?>  
</table>
```

I want to display the results in a table. In the mode, if i change $data[] to $data, i will only get the last record.

Answer (score 0):

Be more simple. You can do like this:

```
//model
public function get_all() {
    return $this->db->get('languages')->result_array();  
}

//controller
public function list_all(){
    $data['content'] = $this->m_languages->get_all();
    $data['title'] = 'Language';

    $data['main'] = 'language_list';
    $this->load->view('admin_template', $data);
}


//view

   <table>
    <?php foreach($content as $c): ?>
          <tr><td><?php echo $c['name']; ?></td></tr> 
         <!-- name is example if column name. You can change it like your table -->
    <?php endforeach; ?>       
</table>
```